# Regex expression php

Tags: php, regex, image

I need simple regex expression correctnes..

this regex

`preg_replace('/(<img.*? class=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . 'myclass' . '$2', $html)`

targets this

`<img src="er" alt="aa" width="641" height="481" class="class1 class2">`

and works ok!

But wordpress generetes ending tag like this /> and regex failes

`<img src="er" alt="aa" width="641" height="481" class="class1 class2" />`

How to correct the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/(<img.*? class=".*?)(".*?\/>)/', '$1 ' . 'myclass' . '$2', $html);
```